# recursive in callback functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, express

I have a function with callback, where I'm using "listTables" method of dynamoDB, which returns just 100 table names and if there is anymore tables, it returns another field called "LastEvaluatedTableName" which we can use in our new query in listTables to query another 100 tables from the mentioned "LastEvaluatedTableName"; how can I have recursion in callbacks in javascript in this logic?

I have tried the following which is not correct:

```
module.exports.ListTables = function (start, callback) {
    var params;
    if (start) {
        params = {
            "ExclusiveStartTableName": start
        };
    }

    dynamodb.listTables(params, function (err, data) {
        var totalData = [];
        totalData.push(data);
        if (data.LastEvaluatedTableName) {
            data = module.exports.ListTables(data.LastEvaluatedTableName);
        }
        callback(err, totalData);

    });
}
```

Please let me know if you need more clarifications!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to concat your data, not replace it each time:

```
dynamodb.listTables(params, function (err, data) {
    if (data.LastEvaluatedTableName) {
        data.concat(module.exports.ListTables(data.LastEvaluatedTableName));
    }
    callback(err, data);
});
```

---

UPDATE

Based on the info from the comment, sounds like you need something like this:

```
module.exports.ListTables = function (start, callback, totalData) {
    var params;
    if (start) {
        params = {
            "ExclusiveStartTableName": start
        };
    }

    if (!totalData) {
        totalData = [];
    }

    dynamodb.listTables(params, function (err, data) {
        totalData = totalData.concat(data.TableNames);
        if (data.LastEvaluatedTableName) {
            module.exports.ListTables(data.LastEvaluatedTableName, callback, totalData);
        }
        else {
            callback(err, totalData);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thansk so much man :-) Actuatly the result of ListTables from Dynamo is like : { LastEvaluatedTableName: 'test100',
  TableNames: 
   [ 'test1',...]} and it seems it is not appending the results!

Comment: You're welcome! Oh, I see, you know how to append the right stuff?

Comment: it is an object so it gives ""Object #<Object> has no method 'concat'" so I tried data.TableNames.concat(module.exports.ListTables(data.LastEvaluatedTableName).TableNames); and this gives "Cannot read property 'TableNames' of undefined"

Comment: The logic seems right, but still "Cannot read property 'TableNames' of undefined"...

Comment: Oh I see what's the problem, you're calling the external function recursively. Let me give you another idea

Comment: You're welcome! :) Haha, now I got all lost and ended up rewriting the whole function, hope it makes sense now. Basically it populates the totalData until there's no more data, in which case if fires the callback.

Comment: Thanks!This is not working always totalData is undefined! Also you missed the case where we have less than 100 tables and with first call we get all tables names!

Comment: Damn, 3AM... forgot to assign the concatted data: `totalData = totalData.concat(data.TableNames);`. The case with no recursion should also work fine with that code.